# Exceptionally weak basicity of pyridine

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, heterocyclic-compounds

It is often explained that the relatively lower basicity of pyridine, relative to most amines, is due to the fact that the $\ce {N}$ lone pair resides in an $\ce {sp^2}$ hybridised orbital, instead of an $\ce {sp^3}$ hybridised orbital. the higher s character of the lone pair-bearing orbital thus holds on to the electron pair more tightly as the lone pair experiences more of the nuclear charge, decreasing the availability of the lone pair for donation to an acid.

Consider the data provided by Clayden, Warren & Greeves (2012), on p. 726. Yes, we observe the lower basicity of pyridine, relative to piperidine. This is consistent with the above rationalisation. However, based on the explanation above, the relative basicities of a typical imine and pyridine should be similar since in both molecules, the lone pair resides in an $\ce {sp^2}$ hybrid. Based on the data, it seems that the basicity of pyridine is around 3 orders of magnitude lower than that of a typical imine. Why is that the case?

[image]

**Reference**

Clayden, J., Greeves, N., & Warren, S. (2012). Organic Chemistry (2nd ed.). New York : Oxford University Press Inc.

Comment: I am not sure a long answer is required. The reason is the aromaticity of pyridine. Write down the two equilibria to see it.

Comment: @Alchimista Well... My educated guess would be aromaticity of the pyridine ring as well. But how exactly does aromaticity play a part in the acid-base behaviour?

Comment: Look at the difference between the two equilibria. Namely the relative stabilization of the charge in the two cases. In pyridine not mesomeric effect are at work without destroying the aromatic sextet. In imines "you can" stabilise the iminiun ion.